# Need to send a message from Chrome Packaged App to a web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I need to send a message from a chrome packaged app to a web page outside of the application. I have no problem sending messages from the web page to the packaged app using

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extID,toSend, function(response) {
   console.log("messag sent to " + extID);
   if(response){
    console.log(response.received);
   }
   else {
   console.log("no reply");
   };
});
```

I can get a reply back from the packaged app. No problem.  But I need to continue to send information from the app to the page beyond the single reply.

I have tried to use this code on the app side:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
  });
  });
}
```

But it does not recognize chrome.tabs as a valid object. When I add: "tabs" to the permissions section of manifest.json, it tells me that tabs permission is not supported in packaged apps.

So is there ANY way to send messages from a Chrome packaged app to an external web page beyond the simple response to a message send from the page itself?

Comment: chrome-app or chrome-extension?

Comment: My program is a chrome app. I need access to the serial port, so I can't use an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in the manifest externally_connectable to include the website domain you are sending from, and you need to use chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal or chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal This is all in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessageExternal).

Comment: Thanks, kzahel. I should have clarified that I do have externally connectable in the manifest, and I am able to receive and respond to messages sent to the webpage. I also looked into using runtime.connect and onConnectExternal, but the docs seemed to suggest that this only works for extensions and not for packaged apps. In any case, what I'm trying to do is to send a message from the app to the web page, NOT simply respond to a message sent from the web page.

Comment: I meant that I can receive and respond to messages sent FROM the web page TO the app.

Comment: Going to take a closer look at runtime.connect now. This might work.

Comment: It works with apps, not just extensions. Yes, onConnectExternal will do the trick. Just have each web page open a connection port to your app, and that way you have bidirectional communication.

Comment: It would be great if you could include an absolute minimum code example for `connect`/`onConnectExternal`.

Comment: Thanks kzahel. Just confirmed that onConnectExternal will do the trick for me. I was confused because the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) I was looking at did not show a way to add an extension ID to the call.

Comment: Yup I agree it's a little confusing that there aren't two separate functions, but the documentation does indeed show you can optionally include the id.